# merging of flow files in the specified order

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new to nifi(using version 1.8.0). I have the requirement of consuming kafka messages which contain vehicle position in the form of lat,lon per message. Since each message will arrive as a flow file, I need to merge all these flow files and make a json file containing the complete path followed by the vehicle. I am using consume kafka processor to subscribe to messages, update attribute processor(properties added are filename:${getStateValue("seq")},seq:${getStateValue("seq"):plus(1)}) to add a sequence number as filename (eg. filename is 1,2, 3 etc) and put file processor to write these files in the specified directory. I have configured FIFO priority queue on all the success relationship between the above mentioned processors.Once, I have received all the messages I want to merge all the flow files. For this I know I have to use get file, enforce order, merge content(merge strategy:bin packing algorithm, merge format:binary concatenation) and put file processor, respectively. Is my approach correct? How should I establish that merging of files takes place in the sequence of their names as filename is a seq number. What should I put in order attribute in enforce order processor?What should in put in group identifier? Are there more custom fields to be added in enforce order processor?

Answer (score 3):

**`EnforceOrder`** processor [documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EnforceOrder/index.html)

**1.Group Identifier**

- This property evaluate on each flowfile for your case use ***`UpdateAttribute`*** Processor, add **group_name** attribute and use the same `${group_name}` attribute in Group Identifier property value.

**2.Order Attribute**

- Expression language is not supported.
- You can use **`filename`** (or) create `new attribute` in
  ***`UpdateAttribute`*** processor and use same attribute name in your
  **`Order Attribute`** property value.

For reference/usage of ***Enforce order*** processor use [this](https://github.com/shureddy/NiFiTemplates/blob/master/enforce-order.xml) template and upload to your NiFi instance.

Comment: I'm struggling with this basic concept. Order Attribute of filename fails for me. I have some dummy files but it will fail out each time. What is wrong with filename as a value for Order Attribute? Is there a special way to write it?